# Android Play Encrypted Video with libmedia :java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

Tags: android, video, encryption

I have basic app which can play encrypted video using libmedia lib.

Video encryption method is working correctly.

But when playing the video it shows this error message

> path is null
>    setDataSource IOException happend : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content  provider: http://127.0.0.1:36316/http://127.0.0.1:36316/storage/emulated/0/AB/b.mp4

Here is my encryption method

```
    public static void encrypt() throws Exception {
    final byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("1234567890123456".getBytes(), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AB/"+"a.mp4");
    final OutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AB/"+"b.mp4"), c);
    while (true) {
        int n = is.read(buf);
        if (n == -1) break;
        os.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    os.close(); is.close();
}
```

Here is my Play button

```
PlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AB/b.mp4");

           try {
              mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           String path = mServer.getURL(file.getPath());

            try {
                mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
                mServer.start();
                path = mServer.getURL(path);
                videoView.setVideoPath(path);
                videoView.start();
            }catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
```

GetCyper() method

```
 private Cipher myGetCipher() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
    // avoid the default security provider "AndroidOpenSSL" in Android 4.3+ (http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/network/#provider)
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ARC4", "BC");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("BrianIsInTheKitchen".getBytes(), "ARC4"));
    return c;
}
```

Compiled with

> compileSdkVersion 23
>   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Error message

```
setDataSource IOException happend : 
                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://127.0.0.1:40208/storage/emulated/0/AB/b.mp4
                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1053)
                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:907)
                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:834)
                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:979)
                                at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:338)
                                at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:248)
                                at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:238)
                                at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoPath(VideoView.java:234)
                                at encrypt.amg.com.encryptiont2.MainActivity$2$override.onClick(MainActivity.java:89)
```

Answer (score 2):

you call the getURL twice.

String path = mServer.getURL(file.getPath());

path = mServer.getURL(path);

Answer (score 2):

The answer of sky is true: fixing the double call to getURL() is mandatory, anyway.

After that, the log entry `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:` is still normal. Note that the message level is not Error but Debug. This is the way the Android player component acts: whatever the path content is, it first tries it as a local resource and if it fails it will fallback to a remote resource. You see that on the next Debug message: `Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side`. At this point, the library is hit.

If the video doesn't play, there is something wrong elsewhere. For example, in your code samples, the cypher is different between the encryption and the decryption (AES/ARC4).

Comment: thank you for the comment.that error was fixed. it was happen because of the cyper key that i used to encrypt .those keys are different from each other. Anyway i want to know that what is the simplest video encryption for a video. Is "ARC4" good? I have used this for 2.8GB video file. but no video is playing.only video loading icon. But this one is playing correctly on small video files (100 MB)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set IVParameters at the decrytion end as well, just like you have done at the encryption end while initializing Cipher.

c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("BrianIsInTheKitchen".getBytes(), "ARC4"), new IVParameterSpec(new byte[16]));